How does "OR if Y is a prime attribute" eliminate redundancy for 3NF?
Assuming the schema R(A,B,C,D,E) with the functional depencies AB -> ABCDE (AB is the superkey) and C -> B (B is a part of the key AB, so the schema is in 3NF for all dependencies).
What does it help that B is part of the key (AB)?
Still it would be possible to have AB -> ... C ... -> B, e.g. (1,2,3,4,5) (2,2,3,4,5) where e.g. C is a department number and B is the number of people working in this apartment. It does not eliminate redundancy, even if C is a prime attribute. The same would happen if C would not be a prime attribute.
So how does this definition eliminate redundancy?
How does the definition part "X -> Y is in 3NF, if ... OR if Y is a prime attribute" (the other preconditions are clear) eliminate redundancy at all?
E.g. having (1,2,3,4,5) and (1,x,3,4,6): To satisfy C -> B, x should be 2, but if x would be 2, AB -> ABCDE wouldn't be satisfied, a contradiction.

This post is extremely unclear. Its writing is redundant, unclear & fragmented & it asks multiple questions--even after I edited it a lot. Use enough words, sentences & references to examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. Don't try to cram everything into one sentence. Ask exactly 1 specific question. Write all that you need to ask it but only that.

Your "I have these FDs"--even given some key info--doesn't make sense. "These are all the FDs that hold"?--Not possible. "These are all the non-trivial FDs that
hold"?--Not possible. "These are some FDs that hold"?--Question can't
be answered. When some FDs hold, per a list and/or keys, all the ones implied by them via Armstrong's axioms also hold. Find out what a cover is & what the exact conditions are needed to apply a particular definition/rule/algorithm. To determine CKs & NFs we must be given FDs that form a cover. See this
answer.

PS "AB is the superkey" doesn't make sense, it isn't the only superkey. Do you mean CK? "the key" is ambiguous, one never knows whether superkey or CK is meant. You seem to mean CK by that. "in 3NF for all dependencies" doesn't make sense; it is tables/schemas that are or are not in NFs. FDs either hold (or as you say, be satisfied) or don't hold in a schema/table. Depending on how a NF definition is phrased sometimes it is reasonable to talk about a FD that holds as violating a NF & its table/schema as not being in that NF because of that FD. But your language doesn't make sense. Etc.

The “or Y is a prime attribute” weakens the normal form, allowing more redundancy, not less (compared to BCNF, which does not have that “or” clause).

How does the definition part […] ... OR if Y is a prime attribute" […] eliminate redundancy at all?

It doesn't. What eliminates redundancy is the other disjunct (“the lhs of every non-trivial FD is a superkey”), which characterizes BCNF and which, as noted by philipxy, removes update anomalies due to FDs. Why that is the case is relatively simple to see: X -> Y asserts that if any two tuples agree on X, then they must agree on Y. So, if I take two tuples with the same values of X attributes and I hide the Y value of one of them, you can infer it by looking at the other tuple. This is the redundancy (information that can be derived from other parts of a relation). By requiring that X is a superkey, you eliminate the problem, because now there cannot be two tuples that agree on X.
Also noted by philipxy is that 3NF was originally defined in terms of transitive (functional) dependencies, and the definition you mention is a (nice) equivalent characterization that was discovered later.
In terms of transitive dependencies, you may informally understand the difference between BCNF and 3NF (hence the relevance of the clause you mention) in these terms: while BCNF forbids all transitive dependencies, 3NF forbids only some of them, specifically those involving attributes that do not belong to any key.
You can always partition the attributes of any relation into two classes: prime attributes (attributes that belong to some key) and what I call “descriptors” (not a widely used terminology), that is, attributes that do not belong to any key. 3NF constrains only the functional dependencies having descriptors on the rhs; BNCF constrains all the functional dependencies.
Using your example:



A
B
C
D
E




a0
b0
c0
d0
e0


a1
??
c0
d1
e1


a2
??
c0
d2
e2



There is only one way to replace the ?? in the instance above in a way that satisfies your FDs: you can infer the value by looking at the first tuple. That is exactly because 3NF doesn't care that AB -> C and C -> B (and C does not functionally determines AB), because B is part of a key.

There is a site format for tables. (For when the table should not instead be initialization code, eg part of a [mre].)

Not sure if you understand, you haven't used the special SO/SE editor table format.

"while BCNF forbids all transitive dependencies" This is not so. 3NF can be defined in terms of certain transitive FDs, but BCNF is not, and the 3NF definition with the disjunct to drop to get BCNF is not in terms of transitive FDs.

Yes, BCNF's definition is not given in terms of transitive FDs, but a consequence of that definition is that a schema in BCNF cannot have any transitive dependency.
Regarding your other point: as you're certainly aware, Codd's and Zaniolo's definitions of 3NF are equivalent. IMO, discussing both makes you better appreciate what 3NF means. The example at the end of my answer has that purpose: adding the “or” clause to the definition of BCNF to obtain the definition of 3NF implies that certain transitive FDs, which were not allowed by BCNF, are now allowed.

3NF does not remove all update anomalies.
3NF was discovered before higher NFs and was defined in terms of transitive FDs, not involving your clause.
Dropping a clause in some 3NF definitions gives BCNF.
BCNF does not remove all update anomalies.
It is the lowest NF where all update anomalies
due to problem FDs (functional dependencies) are removed.
ETNF is the lowest NF where all update anomalies are removed.
They remain absent in higher NFs.
(Which go on through 5NF and end at 6NF).
Update anomalies beyond BCNF are due to problem JDs (join dependencies).
Update anomalies are not the only source of "redundancy".
(A vague, general & multiply-defined term.)

Thank you so much. I wrote "redudancy", for sure it's redundancy :) You can "remove" one column of redundancy by having C -> B, because  for this key column B that causes redundancy, there's only the A column left (and not 2) for varying. Instead, if you would have C -> E (there are two columns, namely the two key columns for varying) (because E is not a prime column). That's the answer I was looking for... I found it out, after asking in various forums... as usual... by drawing it on a sheet of paper

It's like losing one degree of freedom by functional determing a prime attribute instead of a non prime attribute

Please clarify via edits, not comments & delete & flag obsolete comments. But these comments aren't clear. Putting words in scare quotes does not clarify the idiosyncratic meaning that you don't make clear by actually saying what you mean. Metaphors & similes like "losing one degree of freedom" where it's not clear what you mean or what corresponds to what are not helpful. (They just make the writer feel like they said something helpful.) It's not at all clear what you are saying about columns & anyway in FDs it's sets that determine sets (or, sloppily, an attribute for a set of 1 element).

In particular it's not clear what you mean by "redundancy" or "remove" or "remove" in quotes or "a column of redundancy" or "'remove' a column of redundancy" or "varying" or "degree of freedom". Maybe you are trying to talk about decomposing into projections based in some sense on putting FDs into their own table and/or other tables than other FDs. But you are not clear. Get the correct definitions of terms from some competent/good published reference(s)/textbook(s) & use the terms according to the definitions & how they are used in the source. Don't use everyday terms or other terms.
